# Ansible - How to get first column of a list?

Tags: ansible

I need to get the first row of a list in Ansible, I do not know how to do it.
My output is below :

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "vg01  /dev/xvdk",
        "vg01 /dev/xvdj",
        "vg02  /dev/xvdi",
        "vg02  /dev/xvdh",
        "vg03  /dev/xvdg",
        "vg03  /dev/xvdf"
    ]
}
```

I need to get  the first row (vg*).
May be I can do it with a loop on all lines, but I was thinking may be there is an ansible way, like `awk '{print $1}'` ?
Ive tried `split`, but no success.
Someone have a solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, whether you want to get `just the first row` or `first column in all rows` is not clear.

From the output, the input is a list. if we assumed that input is coming as `my_list` and that you are trying to extract first column from all rows, this should give what you want.

```
- name: extract first column
  set_fact:
    extracted_columns: "{{ extracted_columns|default([]) + [item.split(' ')[0]] }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ my_list }}"

- name: display all extracted column as list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ extracted_columns }}"
```

output will be like

```
TASK [display all extracted column as list msg={{ extracted_columns }}] *******************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "vg01",
        "vg01",
        "vg02",
        "vg02",
        "vg03",
        "vg03"
    ]
}
```

`union` filter can be used to get unique values (Note: Reuses extracted values from previous task)

```
- name: extract unique first column
  set_fact:
    extracted_columns_unique: "{{ extracted_columns | default([]) | union(extracted_columns) }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ my_list }}"

- name: display all extracted unique column as list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ extracted_columns_unique }}"
```

output will be like

```
TASK [display all extracted unique column as list msg={{ extracted_columns_unique }}] ******************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "vg01",
        "vg02",
        "vg03"
    ]
}
```

If you want to get first item of the list

```
# using index
- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_list[0] }}"
```

or

```
# using 'first' filter
- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_list | first }}"
```

Comment: Hi Arun, Sorry, as you correctly guessed, I was looking for first column.Edited the question. Thnak you so much. Your answer replies my question. I was thinking may be there is a python function, that would simply sort 1st column, but apparently not. Thanks again!